# How should I split up a Python module into PyPi packages?

Tags: python, package, packaging, pypi

I have written a Python module that I'd like to make available for others. Right now, it is one large module nested into sub-folders:

- wraith

  - util
  - ext
  - color

I think it's best to split these sub-folders up into separate packages. [The tipfy project does this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=tipfy.&submit=search). However, the *ext* and *color* modules depend on *util*.

**What's the best way to organize and release these modules?** Do I split them up and name them  *wraith.util*, *wraith.ext*, and *wraith.color* like tipfy? Do I include *util* when people install *ext* or *color*?

Comment: How big are the sub-modules? Honestly, it's probably simplest to just distribute it as a single package. As long as you're not putting MBs of data onto people's hard drives for no reason, no one is going to care about an extra module or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If wraith.ext etc. are not useful on their own it is not necessary to split. Can you imagine someone would use wrait.util without installing wraith.color?

If you decide to split you need to set **install_requires** in setup.py which tells setuptools etc. the package dependencies. Also you need to set-up **namespace_packages** telling that *wrait* namespace will receive other packages too.

More info

- http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/5-tips-for-packaging-your-python-projects/
- http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html

Comment: wraith.util is the most useful part. ext and color depend on util.